# How to show list items in menu when hover on the parent's it via CSS?

Tags: css

I want when mouse hover (#cssmenu ul > li > ul > li ) Run blow code .Is it possible?

```
#cssmenu ul > li > ul > li > ul {
        right: 1170px;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But what is that code supposed to do? What's the relevant HTML? What are you asking us for help with?

Comment: @DavidThomas the question is quite clear however it is a very specific scenario, the OP could return with another one of these questions involving a different selector or a different level of complexity all together :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the selector you're looking for is:

```
#cssmenu ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    right: 1170px;
}
```

I'm not seeing all the CSS here but this seems like a bad idea in general since you're forcing every 3d level nested `ul` to be `right: 1170px` - if you have multiple of these menu structures they will all be on the same offset.

the `:hover` psuedo selector allows you to *bind* some CSS whenever you're hovering over an element.

for more information on `:hover` -> [docs on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover)

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
#cssmenu ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    right: 1170px;
}
```

Into:

```
#cssmenu ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    right: 1170px;
}
```

and it should work.
As said by [Sidney Liebrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224331/sidney-liebrand)

> the :hover psuedo selector allows you to bind some CSS whenever you're hovering over an element.
>   for more information on :hover -> [docs on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover)

Hope this helps!